# Why can't I select something like iframe > html > body via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wysihtml5

I'm using the [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/) plugin, to add a rich editor to my textarea.

So, the plugin turns this:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

into this:

```
<textarea style="display:none;"></textarea>
<iframe>
  <header>
  <header>
  <body class="wysihtml5-editor">
  </body>
</iframe>
```

I found some info [here](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/104), to add a character counter:

```
  wysihtml5Textarea.data("wysihtml5").editor.observe("load", function() {
    wysihtml5Textarea.data("wysihtml5").editor.composer.element.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      var wysihtml5_cur_length = 0;
      wysihtml5_cur_length = $('.wysihtml5-editor').val().length;
      alert(wysihtml5_cur_length);
    });
  });
```

According to the author of the plugin:

> Solution is to not listen on the textarea for keyup events but instead
>   on the 's body

So that's what I did, I listened to the iframe > html > body: `.wysihtml5-editor`

But right now, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

So it means that the jQuery part is not locating the body for some reason (it does locate elements that are not inside the iframe).

What could be the problem and what are some possible solutions?

[image]

Comment: Because it's an `iframe`. :-)

Comment: @John So, it's there any way of making this work?

Comment: I don't believe. It's the browser's security. It's like detecting a mouse click on a button from `iframe`, I think. But, I am curious about the correct answer, too. Going to make this a favourite questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get at the iframe content via [contentWindow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp)

Something like this works for me:

```
var editor_body = $(".wysihtml5-sandbox").contentWindow.document.body;
$(editor_body).keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You should never use anything from w3schools.com. Visit http://w3fools.com/ and you'll see why.